# Is it possible with Kubeflow to mount a local folder to multiple container ops?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pipeline, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a docker container which contains my environment and then I have 2 files on the local machine which I would like to run. `first_script.py` and `second_script.py` and my image is called `my_env:3.7`.

In the kubeflow I would like to create a pipeline where `first step --> second step`. As the environment is the same for both of the script I would like to use the same docker image, so I just need to add the file to the container. But how can I do that?

I do not want to have 2 separate images for the 2 separate scripts.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Please see my question, as I mention a potential solution (dynamic git clone). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838474/dsl-containerop-with-python